# How could a WCF service become locked?

Tags: wcf, locked

In my application a Winform UI thread in sync calls a WCF method.
99.99% of the time this is ok, but once in a while the call to the WCF method becomes locked and the UI freezes.

I know I can prevent the freezing of UI by making the call async - most of our WCF calls are async - but we considered it not so bad to make this particular tiny method in sync.

When the lock in the WCF service occurs other users cannot access the service as well. I have to restart the WCF service host (Windows service) to resolve the problem.

How is it possible for a WCF service to become locked and inaccessible?
I can't think of a scenario.
We checked the database, which was running as usual.

Technical details:
We use a proxy in a service agent. This service agent with its proxy is kept alive while the application runs.

```
[PreserveReferences]
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, AsyncPattern = false, Action = "MyMethod")]
        MyType MyMethod();
```

The binding in use:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="AppWsHttpBindingConfig" transactionFlow="true" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession ordered="false" enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" establishSecurityContext="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Just to have this clear, are you self hosting your WCF service?

Comment: What kind of binding you have? wsHttp, nettcp???

Comment: @Jonathan we have a Winform client that calls a method on the server; the WCF service is hosted in the Windows service on this server.

Comment: @Yiğit wsHttpBinding; I added the binding config.

Comment: @Gerard It could have something to do with disposing of client proxies. There is this code block for closing/aborting proxies. Have a look at if you don't already. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/9dea384b-d810-429f-80ad-ccaf2c1c36f7/

Comment: @Yiğit Well: for other clients the service was also inaccessible and our Close() implementation is straightforward with an abort in the catch. We only occasionally close however.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the WCF service hang problems is related to disposal of WCF client proxies, which i believe is the problem in your case. If you are not disposing client proxies correctly you will get a timeout exception when you make the (maxConcurrentSessions + 1) n-th call.

Please check out [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/151755/Correct-WCF-Client-Proxy-Closing) article.

Basically it says that, if your channel is not in a faulted state, calling `Abort` on that channel frees the client resources but does not free server resources. For example when a service method throws a `FaultException` it does not put the channel in a faulted state. So calling abort on this proxy will result in an open session in your server with no client.

Wheter this is your case or not, you should consider using the approach described in that article, or some other with the same idea.

Comment: This looks promising, I didn't realize wsHttpBinding uses sessions. How about using establishSecurityContext="false"?

Comment: @Gerard I think it depends on the nature of your service and consuming application. If your client makes a lot of calls in succession or your service gets hit by many request setting this to false will end in a performance breakdown. And i am really guessing that this kind of authentication is not the best at all from a performance point of view. :)